# XeLaTeX PDF Version 2.0

Tags: xetex, pdf

I tried to set the PDF version to the latest 2.0 standard with:

```
\special{pdf:majorversion 2}
\special{pdf:minorversion 0}
```

XeLaTeX seems to ignore this and produces the PDF with default 1.5 version according to Acrobat reader.
Has anyone an idea how to set version 2.0?

Comment: `\special{pdf:majorversion 2}
\special{pdf:minorversion 0}
hello
\bye` works for me.  The PDF file starts with `%PDF-2.0`, and Acrobat reports 2.0 as well.

Comment: Ah interesting! I use TexLive2020 and TeXstudio. Are there any further settings required?

Comment: Hm... I don't have TL 2020 at hand to check now, but if I'm not mistaken, support for `pdf:majorversion 2` was only added for TL 2021...

Comment: What platform are you on? It's possible to 'back port' `(x)dvipdfmx` on Windows at least for this

Comment: I'm on Windows. But honestly have no idea what backport means.

Comment: @DanielStich Means getting a binary from the "future".  I'd recommend you update to TL 21, but if you don't want, then try downloading the `xdvipdfmx.exe` binary from https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/tags/texlive-2021.3/Master/bin/win32/, and copy it to (probably; if you used the default paths) `c:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\xdvipdfmx.exe` (make a copy of the old one for safety, in case it doesn't work).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik in should work in texlive 2020, I have no problems.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed!  Just got home and checked on Linux with TeX Live 2020 and it also works, so... Acrobat reporting the wrong version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This here works fine for me with texlive 2020 on windows:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdf_version_gset:n{2.0}
\pdf_uncompress: % to check the pdf
\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

`\pdf_version_gset:n{2.0}` works also with other engines, so I prefer it over the xetex specific command.

The pdf then starts with

```
%PDF-2.0
```

`hyperref` sets the version too. So if you use it you can

- reset the version after loading it
- or use the new pdfmanagement and set the version there

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{pdfversion=2.0,uncompress}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

- or set the version with hyperref. Be aware that hyperref can only do it if no package or code before has already opened the pdf, so you should check if it worked.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[pdfversion=2.0]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your approach works for me in contrast to the approach with `\special`. But as soon as I add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your MWE, I get the default version 1.5.

Comment: @DanielStich that is one of the reasons why you always should give from the start a complete example. Then people don't have to guess which package you use which interfere. I will add examples with hyperref.